# JOIN 3 Entities in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

This is the first time I develop an Java application and immediately face an issue. Now I have a SQL query as below:

```
Select PD.* From product PD
join Stock SP on PD.id = SP.product_id
join storage SR on SR.id = SP.storage_id
join status ST on ST.storage_id = SR.id
where ST.id ='1qa7n234i'
```

My entities:

```
public class Product extends MainEntity {
   public Product(){}
   public void setAtcKey(String pAtcKey) {
    atcKey = pAtcKey;
   }
}

public class StockPosition extends MainEntity {
   public StockPosition(){}
   @XmlIDREF
    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product pProduct) {
        product = pProduct;
    }

    @XmlIDREF
    public Storage getStorage() {
        return storage;
    }

    public void setStorage(Storage pStorage) {
        storage = pStorage;
    }
}

public class Storage extends MainEntity {
   public Storage(){}
   @XmlTransient
   public Station getStation() {
    return station;
   }

   public void setStation(Station pStation) {
    station = pStation;
   }
}

public class Status extends MainEntity {
   public Status(){}
}
```

So I convert it to CriteriaQuery like:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Product> query = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
Root<Product> product = query.from(Product.class);
Join<StockPosition, Product> sp = product.join(StockPosition_.product);
```

But I got an error message like`The method join(SingularAttribute<? super Product,Y>) in the type From<Product,Product> is not applicable for the arguments (SingularAttribute<StockPosition,Product>)`? This message is very strange for me (because I am newbie). Thank you

Comment: did you mean HQL query?

Comment: I am using: `javax.persistence.criteria.Join`

Comment: Would you explain more and give us more details

Comment: This means that you are trying to build a criteria query. This is not the only way, you can also write queries with [jpql](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html) that is easier for starters. Anyway if you want a criteria query, use the corresponding tag and be aware that _there are_ valuable answers here on SO. If you still need help, post the entities and what you have already done

Comment: I just update my question, thank you, mates.

Comment: You have to reverse the join: `Join<Product, StockPosition> sp = product.join(Product_.stockPositionCollection)` do you have a property like `stockPositionCollection` in `Product` ?

Comment: Actually, I have three entities, Product, StockPosition and Status. StockPosition holds Product_id fk and status_id fk, other entities do not hold stockposition_id but I want to get all records from product entity. Thank you for your quick response @perissf

Comment: Please edit your question by adding the entities and the relevant relationship properties

Comment: I just updated my question

Answer (score 1):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Product> query = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
Root<Product> product = query.from(Product.class);
Join<StockPosition, Product> sp = product.join(StockPosition_.product);
```

I think it should look like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Product> query = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
Root<Product> product = query.from(Product.class);
Join<StockPosition, Product> sp = product.join(Product_.stockposition);
```

Maybe you think to much in a way of SQL joins.

If you don't need to build the query at runtime you may consider to use JPQL instead.

JPQL with NamedQueries:
http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named

Maybe this help you on other questions about JPA
http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria

Do you build the metamodel classes on your own? Or did you use an "Meta Model Generator" provided by your persistence framework?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your join is not correct. If your `Root` is in the `Product` (`Root<Product>`) then you must join using an attribute present in the `Product` class.

In this case, your `Product`class should define an attribute like:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
private List<StockPosition> stackPositions;
```

And then perform the join as follows:

```
Join<Product, StackPosition> sp = product.join(Product_.stackPositions_);
Predicate p = cb.equal(sp.get(StackPosition_.id, "1qa7n234i");
...
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have **one-to-one** relationship in your DB model, then having a class and **Annotation** like below should give you the result.

Basically, you will fetch the `Stock`, and get `stock.storage.status` (which is joined as per the `@javax.peristence.JoinColumn` clause)

```
class Product {

@OnetoOne
@JoinColumn(name="product_id")
Stock stock;

}

class Stock {

@OnetoOne
@JoinColumn(name="storage_id")
Storage storage;

}

class Storage {

@OnetoOne
@JoinColumn(name="storage_id")
Status status;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, dude, but this ways does not help :(